# Remove an event listener inside the scope of the listener

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to remove an event listener inside the event listener itself?

For e.g.:

```
var el = document.createElement('div');

el.addEventListener('message', function(e) {

  //.. do something

  el.removeEventListener( 'message', this );

  el.addEventListener('message', function(e) {

  // something else

});

});
```

It seems that the removeEventListener does not work since the first listener always seems to catch the event when it is triggered.

Comment: Take a look at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723914/remove-eventlistener-in-javascript-after-event-occurred

It's a bit different but i think its a better approach

Comment: `this` **never** refers to the function itself unless explicitly set so (which would be weird). Give the function a name (one way or the other) and refer to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a named function:

```
el.addEventListener('message', doStuff);

function doStuff(e) {

    //.. do something

    el.removeEventListener( 'message', doStuff);

    el.addEventListener('message', function(e) {

        // something else

    });

};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, which doesn't pollute the external scope :

```
el.addEventListener('message', function f(e) {
  //.. do something
  el.removeEventListener('message', f);
  el.addEventListener('message', function(e) {    
     // something else
  });
});
```